# How to point out to link between <a> and </a> in WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

Below is HTML where I need to locate 'Start New Template'.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <a>Start New Template</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
    <li>
        <a>Last Search</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Share code you've tried already

Comment: Hey Sach! Can you update your question with the code you're working with, alongside the error trace-back (IDE, or console error)? As it stands, your question doesn't match a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Also you can try using `ul.dropdown-menu a`(CSS-selector), or `//ul[@class,"dropdown-menu"]/li/a`(Xpath) if the **LinkText** approach failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding it by  xpath,

```
element = findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Start New Template')]"));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16789908)

Comment: I agree, I just wish SO allowed new members to get clarification from askers, makes it real hard to give proper feedback to people. Thanks for the tip.